# C++ | illegal use of structs in classes

Tags: c++, class, struct

```
                    struct Ball {
                    SDL_Surface *picture;
                    SDL_Rect des;
                    SDL_Rect source;
                    int speedX;
                    int speedY;
                };

                class Block {
                public:
                    SDL_Surface *color;
                    SDL_Rect des;
                    SDL_Rect source;
                    bool activation;
                    bool invisibility;

                    bool checkHit (Ball *ball);
                    void makeInvisible();
                };

                bool Block::checkHit(Ball *ball)
                {
                    if (activation)
                    {

                            if (ball->des.x >= Block.des.x && ball->des.x <= Block.des.x + Block.source.w)
                            {
                                ball->speedY *= -1;
                                activation = false;
                                return true;
                            }
                            else return false;
                    }
                }
```

When I want to compile this program , compiler finds an error at Block::checkHit
    error C2275: 'Block' : illegal use of this type as an expression

What can I do ?

Comment: `Block` is a type, so there is no . (dot) operator for it. `Block.des.x` is not a valid statement. Either use `this->des.x` or just `des.x`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access Block's own member variables, just remove the `Block.` parts and you should be ok.

If you want to be absolutely explicit, you could alternatively use use `this->des.x` instead of plain `des.x`.

Answer (score 1):

You're using class name as prefix in your expression. This is invalid syntax, inside the class you don't need prefix to access the members. Replace expressions such as `Block.des.x` with `des.x`.